# IntelliJ IDEA Find In Path show "946F 0E59 9E52 7AA9 8D2D 1EDE EB65 7E8D E028 51F6" by default and this default value cannot be changed

Tags: intellij-idea

**I have tried these things below, but still not work.**

1. clear IntelliJ cache
2. uninstall and install IntelliJ
3. restart pc

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyiJy.png)

Comment: Try disabling custom plugins.

Comment: I have tried this, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I known the reason.
The keyboard shortcut to "OpenPGP: Insert my fingerprint" is command-shift-F, and this shortcut collides with the "Find in path" in Intellij IDEA.

https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/discussions/feedback/12543-please-dont-automatically-set-the-keyboard-shortcuts

[image]

Comment: AWESOME! I've been struggling with this for a bit now, and just stumbled upon your answer - which worked perfectly!!  Thank you, thank you!!